# Stripe Webhook Returning Error 401 and Success

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a checkout session:

```
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: converted_items,
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: process.env.URL + "/order-success.html",
    cancel_url: process.env.URL + `/order-page.html`,
    billing_address_collection: 'required', 
  });
  
  res.json({ id: session.id, order: req.body });
  
});
```

And I would like to set up a webhook so that after a payment is successfully made, **it collects the data from the customer (name, address, products purchased)**

I copied this right from the webhook docs:

```
    const fulfillOrder = (session) => {
    // TODO: fill me in

    console.log("Fulfilling order", session);
}

app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), (request, response) => {
    const payload = request.body;
    const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

    let event;

    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
        return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    }
    console.log(event.type)
        // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
        const session = event.data.object;
        console.log("did order")
            // Fulfill the purchase...
        fulfillOrder(session);
    }

    response.status(200);
});
```

How I am setting it up is I am first running my server on `localhost` and then I am running the testing webhook command from the terminal

```
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/webhook --events=checkout.session.completed
```

When I make a payment, it shows me these messages in the terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've made some modifications to that webhook handler code from the docs. If you're using Checkout and following the docs, what made you switch the code to look for `charge.succeeded`?

You should add some logging to figure out why your server is returning 400, but most likely the verification is failing in `constructEvent`. The snippet you've shared doesn't show you setting `endpointSecret`, but you need to update the value using the secret shown to you when you run `stripe listen`.

You should review the [Checkout fulfillment docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) and focus on `checkout.session.completed` events. You can modify your CLI command to listen to online these events:

`stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/webhook --events=checkout.session.completed`

then your handler would [look like the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#handle-the-checkoutsessioncompleted-event) and you can implement `fulfillOrder` to meet your needs. If you want the details you listed, then you will need to retrieve the session with expansion to include the line items and payment details:

```
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
      'cs_test_123',
      {
        expand: ['line_items', 'payment_intent.payment_method']
      },
    );
```

Then `session.line_items` will be what you created and the name, address and email will be on `session.payment_intent.payment_method.billing_details`.

**Updated to suggest removing signature verification temporarily to diagnose:**

The 400 errors suggest your server is returning an error, most likely as a result of signature verification. I recommend testing a basic endpoint without verification following [this example](http://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build#example-code), to ensure everything else is working as intended. When that is settled, re-adding signature verification is strongly recommended.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had school stuff to work on.  So I have made your corrections and also I just realized that I was using the wrong endpoint secret.  I have now changed it and I think it is working fine now.  However, I have run into another problem.  After re-copying the code from the docs, it does not print any of the console.log statements.  I even added in some of my own to find out if it is even running but nothing gets printed when I make an order on my website.  Does this mean that stripe is not going to the /webhook route?  It shows in my other terminal that the session went through

Comment: Are you receiving any events to your endpoint? Are you using the CLI with `stripe listen` and are you forwarding the events?

Comment: I am using the stripe listen command you mentioned earlier and also changed the code to look for checkout.session.completed. I see that when I make an order it shows it in the cli bit not the terminal where I am running my server.

Comment: Are you using the forwarding function? Can you share your full `listen` command and some example logging lines from the forward result? It should show the response code for each event forwarded.

Comment: Yes, I am running the forwarding function that you provided for me. I am running `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/webhook --events=checkout.session.completed` and I have updated the above to show my new terminal outputs, as well as my changed code.

Comment: The `400` errors suggest your server is returning an error, most likely as a result of signature verification. I recommend testing a basic endpoint without verification following this example, to ensure everything else is working as intended. When that is settled, re-adding signature verification is strongly recommended. 
https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build#example-code

Comment: can you add this as an answer above so I can mark it as the answer

Comment: thanks @StuartFong -- added the debugging approach above to the answer :)